# Using Loopback defined data relations from iOS SDk

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

With reference to

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/

if I have defined a relationship between a customer and an order so that an order belongsTo a customer, how can I get the customer details from the order using the iOS SDK? I'm currently using invokeStaticMethod to get a filtered list, like this:

```
func getOrders() {
    var prototype: LBModelRepository = adapter.repositoryWithModelName("orders")
    adapter.contract.addItem(SLRESTContractItem(pattern: "/orders", verb: "GET"), forMethod: "orders.filter")
    var params = [
                "filter[where][customerId]": "\(self.customerId)",
                "filter[order]": "startDate DESC"
                ]

    var success: SLSuccessBlock = {
                (results: AnyObject!) in
                    var resultsArray = results as NSArray
                    var resultsMutableArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                    for result: AnyObject in resultsArray {
                        resultsMutableArray.addObject(result as NSDictionary)
                    }
                    self.tableData = resultsMutableArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

    var failure: SLFailureBlock = {
                (error: NSError!) -> () in
                }

    prototype.invokeStaticMethod("filter", parameters: params, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

Is it something to do with calling invokeInstanceMethod with a method name of "orders.prototype.customer"? How can I combine the calls efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the include parameter to embed the included relations. See more information at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Include+filter.